# What is the best method for hosting a minecraft server on Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, server, minecraft

I am going to try and run a dedicated Minecraft server on a spare desktop computer of mine. Where I work, we are all into minecraft and want to have a server that we can all use. It cannot be lan as the network is separate for each floor. For easy access, the server should have a graphical interface.

Comment: If you are going for a Minecraft server which is being hosted by another hosting company, then you would need to buy a server from them (I.E: McProHosting).

However, if you want to host it on your spare computer with no cost you would need to portforward. It is also good to add that there is no GUI for hosting a server unless you buy one from a hosting company.

Comment: You're much better off using something like server.pro